# Adding a "difficulty" marker to Org TODOs

Tags: org-mode

I want to add difficulty markers to `TODO`s similar to how priorities are added. For example, the one below is a normal task with a priority of "A" assigned.

```
** TODO [#A] Ask at StackExchange on how to add difficulty markers
** TODO [#B] Work on adding difficulty markers
```

What I want is something like the one below:

```
** TODO [#A][1] Ask at StackExchange on how to add difficulty markers
** TODO [#B][9] Work on adding difficulty markers
```

The numbers denote how difficult the task will be.

Is there an easy way to do this? Is there a package that does something similar that I can look into?

Comment: How about a tag?  `** TODO [#A] Hello world.  :9:`  Or, a property drawer?  `:Difficulty: 9`

Comment: Relying upon the built-in regexp for headlines and property drawers will permit certain highlighting/colorization advantages and also searching/organization -- e.g., `org-search-view`, `org-tags-view`, and `org-agenda-list`.  To change the regexp of a headline will take oneself into the realm of a custom-built `karlo-org-mode` and undoubtedly break a zillion things in the process :)  In an `org-mode` buffer type `M-x describe-variable RET org-complex-heading-regexp RET` to see what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be interested in looking at [Org-Mode Effort Estimates](http://orgmode.org/manual/Effort-estimates.html).

These allow you to attach *time* estimates of how long you anticipate that certain tasks will take. If you also `org-clock` your tasks, you can then compare your *Effort Estimates* to your actual working time, and hopefully improve how accurately you schedule your tasks going forward.

Comment: It is not exactly what I am looking for but is a good solution to my problem. Thanks!